# Salvar texto formatado no DB MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema de notícias e preciso salvar o texto formatado, com quebra de linha, imagens entre um parágrafo e outro e negrito/itálico etc.
Está tudo funcionando o php de postagem, exibição e tudo mais.
Alguém poderia me mostrar como faço para salvar dessa forma? Se possível utilizando o TinyMCE.

Meu código de postagem:

```
<body>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['enviar'])){
    $titulo = mysql_real_escape_string(trim(strip_tags($_POST['titulo'])));
    $postagem = mysql_real_escape_string(trim(strip_tags($_POST['postagem'])));

    $img = $_FILES['foto'];
    $name = $img['name'];
    $tmp = $img['tmp_name'];
    $size = $img['size'];
    $ext = end((explode('.', $name)));
    $pasta = 'imagens';
    $maxSize = 1024 * 1024 * 2;
    $permite = array('jpg','jpeg', 'png');

    if(empty($titulo) && empty($postagem) && empty($name)){
        echo '<script>alert("Por favor, preencha o formulário de postagem corretamente.");</script>';
    }else if(empty($titulo)){
        echo '<script>alert("Por favor, preencha o campo Título.");</script>';
    }else if(empty($postagem)){
        echo '<script>alert("Por favor, preencha o campo Postagem.");</script>';
    }else if(empty($name)){
        echo '<script>alert("Por favor, selecione uma imagem.");</script>';
    }else if(!in_array($ext, $permite)){
        echo '<script>alert("A extensão da imagem selecionada não é suportada.");</script>';
    }else if($maxSize < $size){
        echo '<script>alert("A imagem selecionada é grande demais.");</script>';
    }else{
        $name = uniqid().'.'.$ext;
        $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO postagem (titulo, postagem, imagem) VALUES ('$titulo', '$postagem', '$name')") or die(mysql_error());
        if($sql){
            $upload = move_uploaded_file($tmp, $pasta.'/'.$name);
            if($upload){
                echo '<script>alert("Postagem salva com sucesso!");</script>';
            }else{
                echo '<script>alert("A postagem não pôde ser salva corretamente.");</script>';
            }
        }else{
                echo '<script>alert("Desculpe, ocorreu um erro.");</script>';
            }
    }
}
?>
<div class="formulario">
    <div id="form_limites">
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <a class="textos">Título.:</a><br>
    <input type="text" id="titulo" name="titulo" maxlength="80"><br>
    <br><a class="textos">Conteúdo da postagem.:</a><br>
    <textarea type="text" id="postagem" name="postagem"></textarea><br>
    <br><a class="textos">Imagem.:</a><input type="file" id="foto" name="foto"><br>
    <input type="submit" id="enviar" name="enviar" value="Salvar postagem">
</form>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

**Problema:** Meu texto simplesmente não retorna formatado na hora de exibir no site. Ele vem em uma só linha.

Comment: Qual o seu problema, afinal? Qual erro você está recebendo? Por que você não está conseguindo? Aparentemente está tudo certo.

Comment: Meu texto simplesmente não retorna formatado na hora de exibir no site. Ele vem em uma só linha.

Comment: Me mostre como ele está sendo trazido do banco. Digo, como ele aparece para você. E, onde você está exibindo ele? Podes me mostrar como você faz o `SELECT` em uma postagem?

Comment: Posso sim, a seguir o meu SELECT.: <?php
 $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM postagem ORDER BY data DESC LIMIT 3");
 $conta = mysql_num_rows($sql);
 
 if($conta <= 0){
  echo '<h2 class="textos">Nenhuma postagem encontrada.</h2>';
 }else{
  while($res = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
?>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se o texto formatado pelo TinyMCE possuir html, remova o [strip_tags](http://php.net//manual/pt_BR/function.strip-tags.php) de `$postagem`. Essa função remove todas as tags html logo o texto será gravado no banco sem nenhuma formatação.

mude:

```
$postagem = mysql_real_escape_string(trim(strip_tags($_POST['postagem'])));
```

para:

```
$postagem = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['postagem']));
```