# Como salvar HTML em Mysql

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, banco-de-dados

Estou com um impasse em relação a armazenar um HTML no BD.
Estou utilizando a  propriedade em php: `htmlentities($_POST['codhtml'])` para realizar esta operação. Porém ao salvar um código como:

```
<span class="frase-aditivo mover" id="adt6-enable" style="transform: translate3d(-2px, 202px, 0px); cursor: move; touch-action: none; -webkit-user-select: none; z-index: 1004; border: 3px dashed red; font-size: 112px; font-family: &quot;Comic Sans MS&quot;; color: rgb(0, 64, 128);">Leve a alegria do Natal para sua casa ! </span>
```

No banco fica armazenado:

```
&lt;span class=&quot;frase-aditivo mover&quot; id=&quot;adt6-enable&quot; style=&quot;transform: translate3d(-2px, 202px, 0px); cursor: move; touch-action: none; -webkit-user-select: none; z-index: 1004; border: 3px dashed red; font-size: 112px; font-family:
```

Ou seja, por algum motivo o código  é perdido sempre que há uma URL ou apos "font-family:".

Qual a melhor maneira de realizar esse salvamento ?

PS. Estou utilizando LongText.

Obrigado =D

/* CONTINUAÇão CODIGO*/

```
$("#mt_finalizar").click(function(event) {
      var codhtml = '<span class="frase-aditivo mover" id="adt6-enable" style="transform: translate3d(-2px, 202px, 0px); cursor: move; touch-action: none; -webkit-user-select: none; z-index: 1004; border: 3px dashed red; font-size: 112px; font-family: &quot;Comic Sans MS&quot;; color: rgb(0, 64, 128);">Leve a alegria do Natal para sua casa ! </span>';

      $.ajax({

            type      : 'post',

                url       : 'salvarDados.php',

                data      : 'codhtml='+codhtml
                            +'&motivoid=2'
                            +'&formatoid=2'
                            +'&motivonome=Nome',
                dataType  : 'html',

                success : function(txt){
                     alert("Sucesso,");
                },
                error: function(result) {
                    alert("Erro ao Salvar");
                }
      });



$resultado = $this->conexao->exec("INSERT INTO tabela (col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col_codhtml,col6) VALUES(2,2,2,2,2,'$codhtml','Nome')");
```

Comment: Eu utilizo o base64_encode e o base64_decode quando salvo HTML no banco.

Comment: @MayronCeccon péssimo hábito. Ocupa muito mais espaço, e não tem vantagem nenhuma. Além disso é um processo de codificação e um de decodificação a mais totalmente desnecessário. Fica a sugestão de aprender melhor a usar o DB e os recursos da linguagem para melhorar seus aplicativos.

Comment: Cara, sei que o tipo blob salva arquivo e tals, acho válido tu testar com ele.

Comment: Tentei utilizar este base_64 porém a String é interrompida da mesma maneira. Vou tentar utilizar o tipo blob.

Comment: @user48796 seu problema não deve estar no DB, provavelmente está no jeito que está fazendo o insert. Mesmo que funcionasse, base64 só iria disfarçar o problema. Só que se não postar o código na pergunta, não vai dar certo. Provavelmente sua pergunta já foi resolvida neste post: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21318/70

Comment: @Bacco Obrigado pelo apoio ! Acredito que o erro esta na hora que passo por paramentro o HTML, quando ele encontra o '&' ele interpreta como um novo parametro... Teria uma solução para isso ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Na parte do JS troque isso:

```
data      : 'codhtml='+codhtml
```

por isso:

```
data      : 'codhtml='+encodeURIComponent(codhtml)
```

O `encodeURIComponent` serve para "escapar" os caracteres especiais que normalmente são usados em valores de URL ou POST.

Na parte do PDO troque isso:

```
$resultado = $this->conexao->exec("INSERT INTO tabela
(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col_codhtml,col6)
VALUES(2,2,2,2,2,'$codhtml','Nome')");
```

por isso:

```
$resultado = $this->conexao->exec('INSERT INTO tabela 
(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col_codhtml,col6)
VALUES(2,2,2,2,2,'.$this->conexao->quote($codhtml).',"Nome")');
```

(quebrei as linhas só pra facilitar a leitura)

O `quote` troca os caracteres que podem conflitar com a Query, evitando que aspas e caracteres de escape corrompam a string. Ele também acrescenta aspas nas "pontas" da string

O ideal mesmo seria usar *prepared statements*. Veja exemplos nessa questão:

> [Como prevenir injeção de código SQL no meu código PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3864/70)

Comment: Olá amigo, não conhecia essa propriedade no Jquery. Funcionou perfeitamente. Obrigado !

Comment: Que bom que resolveu. Só um detalhe, o encodeURIComponent não é do jQuery, é do Javascript mesmo. Mesmo se não usar jQuery, ele funciona.